# Matching multiple words Regex , python

Tags: python, regex

i need to match a pattern from a string. The string is variable so i need to develop some amount of variability in it .
What i need to do is extract words occurring with "layout" and they occur in 4 different manners

```
1 word -- layout` eg: hsr layout

2words -- layout eg: golden garden layout

digit-word -- layout eg: 19th layout

digit-word word --layout eg:- 20th garden layout
```

It can be seen that i need the digits field to be optional. a single regex must do it. here's what i did:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?:\d*)?\w+\s(?:\d*)?\w+l[ayout]*')
text = "opp when the 19th hsr layut towards"
q = re.findall(p,text)
```

i need 19th hsr layout in this expression. but the above code returns none. What is the problem with my code above?

Some string examples are:

```
str1 = " 25/4 16th june road ,watertank layout ,blr"  #extract watertank layout 
str2 = " jacob circle 16th rusthumbagh layout , 5th cross" #extract 16th rustumbagh layout
str3 = " oberoi splendor garden blossoms layout , 5th main road"  #extract garden blossoms layout
str4 = " belvedia heights , 15th layout near Jaffrey gym" #extract 15th layout
```

Comment: What exactly to you mean by 'connected with "layout"'?

Comment: words that occur with the word layout.. 4 conditions given above..

Comment: Your example text says "layot" not "layout"

Comment: well ,yes.. i accounted for it using l[ayout]* for any mistakes in text..

Comment: Do you want this? `r'(?:\w+\s+){1,2}layout'`

Comment: @falsetru : this also isnt returning anything. Could u create a regex for above 4 possibilities?

Comment: Please, explain in some other words or provide string examples, you would like to be matched. I neither understand, what is "words that occur **with** the word".

Comment: @Sword, It matches as expected. I posted an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `r'(?:\w+\s+){1,2}layout'` as I commented:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'(?:\w+\s+){1,2}layout')
>>> p.findall(" 25/4 16th june road ,watertank layout ,blr")
['watertank layout']
>>> p.findall(" jacob circle 16th rusthumbagh layout , 5th cross")
['16th rusthumbagh layout']
>>> p.findall(" oberoi splendor garden blossoms layout , 5th main road")
['garden blossoms layout']
>>> p.findall(" belvedia heights , 15th layout near Jaffrey gym")
['15th layout']
```

`{1,2}` is used to match at most 2 words.

Comment: @Sword, `\w` matches word character. Word characters include alphabets, digits and `_`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work -

```
import re

l = [" 25/4 16th june road ,watertank layout ,blr",
" jacob circle, 16th rusthumbagh layout , 5th cross",
" oberoi splendor , garden blossoms layout , 5th main road",
" belvedia heights , 15th layout near Jaffrey gym",]

for ll in l:
    print re.search(r'\,([\w\s]+)layout', ll).groups()
```

Output:

```
('watertank ',)
(' 16th rusthumbagh ',)
(' garden blossoms ',)
(' 15th ',)
```